# Laravel, get currently logged-in users

Tags: authentication, laravel

I want to display a list of currently logged-in users in an app. I want to use Laravel Auth method. I'm looking at the API and I cannot find anything like it.

I would probably need to loop through the sessions store and then match it to a user ID. Am I right?

UPDATE: Forgot to mention, I'm storing sessions in the DB.

Answer (score 27):

"Currently logged in" is something you can't do with plain old sessions. Let me explain why:

A session is a bunch of data stored at server side which is assigned to an user through a cookie. That cookie remains on user browser and so it keeps the session active. Sessions can stay "alive" months without the user even logging in.

**But,** it's possible to [store sessions on database](http://laravel.com/docs/session/config#database).

As you can see, Laravel keeps a field called `last_activity` and, through that field, you should be able to retrieve all sessions that had activity within the last 15 minutes (or something else, you call it).

When your retrieve those records, the `data` field is a serialized representation of session data. You can `unserialize($session_record->data)` and retrieve the user id.

Depending on your Auth driver, session's user id may have different names:

- For eloquent driver, it should be `eloquent_login`.
- For fluent driver `fluent_login`.
- For your `Custom\AuthClass`, it should be called `custom_authclass_login`.

Comment: Mission, can you be a bit more specific about your real doubt? We can then provide a more precise answer.

Comment: @vFragosop, he has no doubts, he just knew the details from your informative answer, and then said, huh, its easy and i knew about that, why bother then. Ignore him buddy, you had the best answer.

Comment: Sessions can NOT stay "alive" months - `config('session.lifetime')` has it set in minutes, by default it is 120 minutes.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev what happens if your `session.lifetime` is changed to `86400` minutes? It does stay alive for 60 days, doesn't it? So yes, sessions can stay alive for months.

Comment: I'm not using database for session, I use Redis. And I don't have `last_activity`. I guess that is why you can have the session records kept for months. Because no process there to delete the outdated records from the database. Redis cleans itself with different procedures. Thank you for the useful details about the case where the session data is kept in the database. I see now, I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that all http requests from logged in users are passing `auth` middleware, we can override `terminate` function like following:

```
public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    Auth::user()->save();
}
```

Then a query like `User::where('updated_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(12))->get();` will bring all logged in user, where `12` is the lifetime of session.

Of course, for real time, we should use `ajax` calls every 5 seconds or websockets via `pusher` or other.

Comment: `pusher` + `Webhook`, I mean.

Answer (score -2):

**First create a table where the logged in user's id will be inserted**

```
Schema::create('active_users', function(Blueprint $table)

{

                    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
                    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

                    $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Then in yourcontroller insert data while logging in**

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

                  DB::table('active_users')->insert(array('user_id' =>   Auth::id()));
}
```

**and delete the data while logging out**

```
DB::table('active_users')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->delete();
```

**Print the online users list in your view**

```
<ul><strong>Online Users</strong>
            <?php $online_users = DB::table('active_users')->where('user_id','!=',Auth::id())->get(); ?>

            @foreach($online_users as $online_user)
                <li>{{User::find($online_user->user_id)->first_name}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
```

Comment: What will happen when a session times out?

Comment: When session times out , delete the row from active_users table.

Comment: @PankajSuthar HOW ? ( When session times out , delete the row from active_users table. )