# Check if a user other than myself is logged in (Laravel) (Redis)

Tags: laravel, authentication, redis

I want to see a list of users with a statuses - logged in or not

Something like:

```
Auth::check($student->id)
```

I'm using Redis for sessions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel, get currently logged-in users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632144/laravel-get-currently-logged-in-users)

Comment: Thank you, It is close, but not my case, and it doesn't have an answer. I updated the question.

Comment: maybe you can create a new column for that? then if they're logged in you update it and if they log out you update it.

Comment: @Jovs, thank you, but I already have the data in Redis, I just need to get it out. Laravel stores data in Redis somehow.